# Orthogonality of nonpolynomial 2F1 hypergeometric function

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, hypergeometric-function

The solutions to the Jacobi differential equation:
$\left(1-x^{2}\right)y''(x)+(\beta -\alpha -(\alpha +\beta +2)x)y'(x)+n(n+\alpha +\beta +1)y(x)=0,$
are hyper-geometric functions

$\,{}_{2}F_{1}\left(-n,1+\alpha +\beta +n;\alpha +1;{\tfrac  {1}{2}}(1-x)\right),$

Imposing boundary conditions in the region $(-1,1)$, we get the Jacobi polynomials, namely, these functions (in some normalization) with $n$ positive integer.

**From now on let us specify to $\beta=0$ for simplicity.**

However, if one wants to span the relevant space of functions on $(1,\infty)$, one ends up with the family of functions with $n=-\frac{\alpha+1}{2}+i\rho$ with real $\rho$.

In principle, orthogonality with the weight function $(1-x)^{\alpha}$ follows from the fact that these are eigen-functions with different eigenvalues and appropriate boundary conditions.

My questions are (answers to any would be great!):

1) How does one find the normalization? Doing the integrals explicitly is very hard even numerically (the integrand decays only as $1/x$ but is oscillatory)

2) Is there a way to establish the space these functions span as a function of $\rho$? (Maybe the most important part of the question for me)

3) Should there be an orthogonality relation also in $\rho$ space?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi Yuriy, thanks for the note. All of them should be x.... edited now

Comment: I don't know the answers, but if you have a continuous eigenvalue $\rho$ then you should probably normalize to delta function, i.e. $$\int_1^\infty f_\rho (x) f_{\rho'}(x)dx=\delta(\rho-\rho')$$ Where $f_\rho(x)$ are properly normalized eigenfunctions. Integrating the above equation w.r.t. $\rho'$ over the whole range helps define the normalization constant. I agree, the integrals might be complicated. Is this how you were doing this? Or did you define the normalization some other way?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I would definitely want to normalize to a delta function, in the same way you are suggesting. Indeed the problem is that the integration is hard even numerically. It's possible that one can do it using some (sum or integral) representation of 2F1.

Actually, when I wrote this question part (1) was the most important for me. However, my circumstances have changed, and while part (1) and (3) are still important, part (2) is the crucial part now.

Comment: BGS, sorry to say I don't have enough of a mathematical background to answer the second question. As for the first, I'll look into this when I have some time